# Dudas ficheros y listas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, archivo

estoy empezando a programar en python, y me han pedido hacer un menú que pida al usuario el código,nombre,apellido,ciudad y añadir esto a un fichero.

He estado pensando y se me viene a la mente, crear una lista donde introducir los datos introducidos por el usuario y luego pasar esa lista a un fichero... lo he intentado de varias formas pero no consigo que el programa funcione...si alguien puede resolverme par de dudas seria de mucha ayuda, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] kisloty. Te recomiendo mirarte [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y como realizar buenas preguntas. Debes mostrar que has intentado (sin importar que no funcione o que esté mal) y tu duda o problema concreto para que la pregunta se adecue al sitio y podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a continuación te dejo la manera más simple de hacer el menú usando `input` en caso de que el registro de datos sea para un solo usuario:

```
lista = []

lista.append(input("Introduce tu código: "))
lista.append(input("Introduce tu nombre: "))
lista.append(input("Introduce tu apellido: "))
lista.append(input("Introduce tu ciudad: "))

file = open("datos.txt", "w") 
file.write("Codigo: " + lista[0] + "\n") 
file.write("Nombre: " + lista[1] + "\n") 
file.write("Apellido: " + lista[2] + "\n") 
file.write("Ciudad: " + lista[3] + "\n") 

file.close()
```

En caso de que quieras guardar varios registros de usuarios y usando listas como has indicado(sería más correcto y sencillo con diccionarios) sería tal que así:

```
lista = []
menu = True
i = 1

while(menu == True):
    lista.append(input("Introduce tu código: "))
    lista.append(input("Introduce tu nombre: "))
    lista.append(input("Introduce tu apellido: "))
    lista.append(input("Introduce tu ciudad: "))
    opt = input("¿Desea continuar? (s/n): ")
    if(opt == "n"):
        menu = False

file = open("datos.txt", "w") 
while(i*4<=len(lista)):
    file.write("Codigo: " + lista[1*i-1] + "\n") 
    file.write("Nombre: " + lista[1*i] + "\n") 
    file.write("Apellido: " + lista[2*i] + "\n") 
    file.write("Ciudad: " + lista[3*i] + "\n\n")
    i += 1

file.close()
```

Este script actualizaría el archivo solo la primera vez y sobrescribiría su contenido en caso de añadir registros cada vez que ejecutas el script tendría que abrir el archivo usando `file = open("datos.txt", "a")` usando el "Appending mode" para así añadir las nuevas líneas de texto.

Espero ser de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Buenas y perdona porque no pude responder antes, `raw_input` extrae el valor que introduzcas por teclado siempre como una string en cambio `input` evalua si es un int, str, float, etc. No te acostumbres a usar raw_input ya que en python 3.x ya no existe y debes hacer el caswting tu mismo haciendo por ejemplo `int(input("Introduce:"))` o `str(input("Introduce:"))`. Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: @DSGDSR usar `input` en Python 2.x (o `eval` en Python 3) para entradas de usuario sin filtrar adecuadamente es como encender un fuego para secarte después de haberte derramado una lata de gasolina encima... XD. No es que haga el casting por ti, acepta y evalúa  cualquier expresión Python válida, lo que implica que un usuario con intenciones dudosas pueda causar estropicios considerables, más conocido como ataque de  inyección de código. Es cierto que se trata de una tarea académica en este caso, pero no deja de ser una muy mala práctica que se debe evitar. Un saludo.